# What does "ERC" stand for?

Tags: protocol, eip

As seen as a label for EIPs (Ethereum Improvement Proposals): https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/labels/ERC

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Its **Ethereum Request for Comments**

Ethererum Specific of [wiki/Request_for_Comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)

[This](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/16) is interesting